# Stretched sections in plotting

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

```
x = linspace(0,10,100)
```

Gives me 100 equal section from 0 to 10. How can I get some stretched sections, e.g, 60 sections from 0 to 2 and 40 sections from 2 to 10?

Can anyone please tell me? I am using python 2.7.2
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.concatenate([np.linspace(0, 2, 60), np.linspace(2, 10, 40)])
```

or to avoid repeating 2 :

```
np.concatenate([np.linspace(0, 2, 60), np.linspace(2, 10, 40)[1:]])
```